# In a Hausdorff space, for any open set $U$, can we find another open set $V$ such that $\overline{V} \subseteq U$?

Tags: general-topology

> In a Hausdorff space $X$, for any point $x \in X$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ containing $x$. Can we find another open set $V$ containing $x$ such that $\overline{V} \subseteq U$?

This is not a homework question or anything, but if it is true it would give me an easy way to prove the reverse direction of another theorem.

Loosely this reminds me of the separation axioms, but I'm not sure if this holds for Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: The property you want $X$ to have is called "regularity". You are asking whether every Hausdorff space is regular. No, there are counterexamples.

Comment: You didn't say it quite right, but I think you meant to say that for any paint $x\in X$ and **for any** neighborhood $U$ containing $x$ . . ..

Comment: @bof No I just need one neighborhood $U$ containing $x$ for this to hold, not the full strength of regularity

Comment: $X$ is a neighborhood of $U,$ so why don't you take $U=X$ and $V=X?$

Comment: @bof Ahh that won't work either, I needed neighborhoods that are neither $X$ nor $\emptyset$. But if you change your comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: If $X=\{x\}$ there is no alternative to $U=V=X.$ Otherwise, if $X$ is a Hausdorff space with more than one point, and if $x$ is any point in $X,$ then we can choose a point $y\in X\setminus\{x\}$ and we can find disjoint open sets $V,W$ with $x\in V$ and $y\in W.$ Now $U=X\setminus\{y\}$ is an open neighborhood of $x,$ and $V$ is an open neighborhood of $x,$ and $\overline V\subseteq U.$

Comment: @bof Your last comment fully answers my question. If you type it up as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 2):

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology $\tau_0$. Let $\tau:= \{V\cup (U\cap \mathbb{Q}) \mid U,V\in \tau_0\}$. It is easy to see that $\tau$ is a Hausdorff topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Denote by $X$ the set $\mathbb{R}$ together with the topology $\tau$. Pick $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ and let $U:=\mathbb{Q}$ be the open neighborhood of $x$ in $X$. Let $V$ be any $V\in \tau$ with $x\in V\subset U$. It follows from the definition of $\tau$ that there is a $W\in \tau_0$ with $V = U \cap W$. There exists an irrational number $p\in W$ since irrational numbers are dense in $\mathbb{R}$. I claim $p$ must lie in the closure $\overline{V}$ of $V$ in $X$. If not, then $O:=X\backslash \overline{V} \in \tau$ is an open neighborhood of $p$ in $X$. It follows from the construction of $\tau$ that there is an $O'\in \tau_0$ with $p\in O' \subset O$. Because rational numbers are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, we have $\emptyset \neq O'\cap W \cap \mathbb{Q} = O' \cap V$. This is a contradiction. Therefore $\overline{V}$ does not lie in $U$.